# error no se puede transformar un objeto DBNULL

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una aplicación en donde lleno un `gridview` con una consulta `SQL`, pero al querer registrar más información en el `gridview` me presenta el siguiente error:

> No se puede transformar un objeto DBNULL en otros tipos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
if (DialogResult.OK == miBskReten.ShowDialog()) 
{ 
    codRet = miBskReten.sCodigo; 
    detRet = miBskReten.sDetalle; 
    idRtn = miBskReten.iIdRtn; 
    PrcRet = miBskReten.dPorcen; 
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Codigo"].Value = codRet; 
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Detalle"].Value = detRet; 
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["idRetencionIVARenta"].Value =Convert.ToString(idRtn); 
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Porcentaje"].Value =Convert.ToString(PrcRet); 
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Valor"].Value =Convert.ToString(PrcRet*dBase); 
}
```

En esta parte de registrar la información en el `grid` no logro decirle al grid que se registre un nuevo dato.

Comment: Estás seguro de que la excepción se lanza en esas líneas? Que valor le estas pasando en `codRet` y `detRet`?

Comment: Hola Gracias por responder, y de acuerdo a tu pregunta en el campo codRet es una variable alfanumerica string "075" y en detRet es una variable string "BIENES Y SERVICIOS"

Comment: Mi código completo es el siguiente
if (DialogResult.OK == miBskReten.ShowDialog()) {
codRet = miBskReten.sCodigo;
detRet = miBskReten.sDetalle;
idRtn = miBskReten.iIdRtn;
PrcRet = miBskReten.dPorcen;
this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Codigo"].Value = codRet;
this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Detalle"].Value = detRet;
this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["idRetencionIVARenta"].Value =Convert.ToString(idRtn);
this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Porcentaje"].Value =Convert.ToString(PrcRet);
this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Valor"].Value =Convert.ToString(PrcRet*dBase);
}

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver en el código que muestras, `codRet`, o `detRet` ,o `idRtn` o `PrcRet` es `DBNull` y al intentar hacer el Convert te salta la excepción.

Para solucionarlo solo necesitas comproibar que no sean  `DBNull` antes de intentar hacer cualquier conversión.

Para ello solo necesitas hacer algo como esto:

```
if (DialogResult.OK == miBskReten.ShowDialog())
{
    codRet = miBskReten.sCodigo;
    detRet = miBskReten.sDetalle;
    idRtn = miBskReten.iIdRtn;
    PrcRet = miBskReten.dPorcen;
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Codigo"].Value = codRet;
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Detalle"].Value = detRet;
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["idRetencionIVARenta"].Value = Convert.ToString(idRtn is DBNull ? 0 : idRtn);
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Porcentaje"].Value = Convert.ToString(PrcRet is DBNull ? 0 : PrcRet);
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["Valor"].Value = Convert.ToString((PrcRet is DBNull ? 0 : PrcRet) * (dBase is DBNull ? 0 : PrcRet));
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, el problema se da cuando intento actualizar el ultragrid, ya que las variables que las obtengo no son DBNULL, el problema esta en el ultragrid es como que se encuentra bloquedo pero no logro hacer que se active.

Comment: podrías poner una captura de cuando da la excepción y de la línea y la excepción?